# Secure html+php form to upload image and vector files?

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, graphics

I trying to do a form which accepts raster graphics and vector graphics files (it can be: jpg, gif, psd, png, svg, eps, ai, cdr, pdf and others) and I want to avoid malicious files.

The options I have found:

1) Custom function filtering extensions: it seems not ellegant - lot extensions to type and maybe I can forget one - and it does not seem much secure. Or is it?

2) [getimagesize function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to check file type: it doesn't work with vector file - at least it was what I understood. Or am I wrong?

I did not find any page on web talking about raster + vector files form. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

The PHP file which receives de uploaded file:

```
// get the name of original file    
$imagem = $_FILES['arquivo']['name']; 

// handle string to get extension in lower case. I think it is not a very secure handler.
$ext = strtolower(substr($imagem, strrpos($imagem, '.') + 1)); 

// array of extensions the validation accepts
$valid_ext = array ('ai', 'bmp', 'cdr', 'eps', 'gif', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'pdf', 'png', 'psd', 'svg');    

// checking
if(in_array($ext,$valid_ext)){ 
     // file is ok. Do something
}
```

I tryed to do it first  checking Mime with `file types`, `$file_info`, `finfo()`, `getimagesize()` but any of these worked well. I got some problem with identifying EPS and CDR extensions. It returns "application/octet-stream" that is the Mime Type file for unknown extensions. In my research, I understood that is the browser who send the Mime File Type information based on OS, so we have a problem where every form user can have a different Mime File Type for the same extension.

I understood too that PHP has a standard file to identify Mimes, but I could not handle the file to add info about EPS and CDR file.

So I had to use that string check solution.